# Tiled Game Background and the "'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" error

Tags: pygame

I am working my way through an entry level Pygame tutorial on a Windows 7 machine and for the following code, I am getting this error:

"builtins.TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

# 6 - Draw the screen elements

```
for x in range(width//grass.get_width()+1):
    for y in range(height//grass.get_height()+1):
        screen.blit(castle,(0,30))
```

Through my research on this site I found that using the int division separator (//) got me past the error, but alas my grass image won't tile.  I know this code works with (/) on my Linux machine because I have completed the game previously.  If you take the time to look into this I truly appreciate your help!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that the problem is because in your loop you are bliting a castle, and not a grass tile.

this should fix it:

```
screen.blit(grass,(x*grass.get_width(),y*grass.get_height())
```

Comment: Thank you!  I found the problem (a omitted line that nudged this castle line upward) and corrected it.  I also learned about the difference in / and //having made this mistake.